# Controller not being read angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using WAMP and under my www folder i have a folder called ng-cribs. 
the index has the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/cribsController.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>ng-cribs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body ng-app="ngCribs" ng-controller="cribsController">

    <h1> {{hello}} </h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Then i have a app.js file in the same folder with the following code

```
angular.module('ngCribs, ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Then lastly a controller file under a new folder called scripts nad the file name is cribsController with the following code

```
angular
.module('ngCribs')
.controller('cribsController'), function(&scope){

    $scope.hello = 'hello world!'

});
```

However my result is `{{Hello}}` instead of displaying what is in the controller

Comment: are you sute the path is correct?

Comment: On your script references you have not loaded angularjs is it a typo?

Comment: Did you mean $scope instead of &scope?

Comment: Also your controller declaration syntax isn't quite right...

Comment: I don't see any angular.js dependencies

Answer (score 0):

In the controller function, you must use `$` instead of `&`.

```
angular
.module('ngCribs',[])
.controller('cribsController', function($scope){
    $scope.hello = 'hello world!'
});
```

Comment: can i check hif the script is actually being brought in. if so how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

> You should declare syntax as below

```
angular
.module('ngCribs').controller('cribsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.hello = 'hello world!'
}]);
```

> instead of

```
angular
.module('ngCribs')
```

> Results in closing the controller without declaring its dependencies and
>   injections.

```
.controller('cribsController'), function(&scope){

    $scope.hello = 'hello world!'

});
```